# Como resolver java.lang.NullPointerException?

Tags: java, exceção, thread, nullpointerexception

Criei a classe `Server`! Contudo é lançada uma exception do tipo `java.lang.NullPointerException`! Será que alguém me podia ajudar neste problema?

A classe é a seguinte:

```java
public class Server {

    public static final int SERVERPORT = 8888;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {



        System.out.println("Starting echo server...");
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);

        boolean condition = true;

        while (condition)
        {
            Socket s = ss.accept();

            try
            {
                InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

                String msg = br.readLine();

                boolean condition1 = true;
                while (condition1) {

                    System.out.println(msg);
                    msg = br.readLine();

                    if(msg.equals("quit")){
                        condition1=false;
                    }
                }

                if(msg.equals("quit")){
                    condition=false;
                }

            }
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                System.err.println("I/O error: " + ioe.getMessage());
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    s.close();
                }
                catch (IOException ioe)
                {
                    assert false; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Onde dá o erro?

Comment: O erro aponta para a seguinte instrução:     if(msg.equals("quit"))

Comment: @MarcoAF Se o conteúdo da stream acabar antes da mensagem `quit` chegar, o `br.readLine()` vai retornar `null`. Não há muita saída a não ser testar por isso... (ou garantir seja lá como que nunca vai faltar o `quit` no final) P.S. Você lê a mensagem, imprime na tela, depois lê de novo - como saber se a primeira mensagem recebida já não foi o quit?

Comment: Não vou conseguir te ajudar mas já que eu modifiquei o código para eu entender melhor fica a dica de uma lógica sem *flags*. http://ideone.com/aiXooY

Comment: @bigown -> http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2333/por-que-muitas-pessoas-respondem-nos-coment%C3%A1rios-em-vez-de-criar-uma-resposta - fica a dica :)

Comment: @Victor não acredito que isto responde a pergunta de fato. Não tenho o Java aqui para testar corretamente.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O seu erro ocorre aqui:

```java
if(msg.equals("quit")){
```

Na verdade, há duas linhas assim. Uma forma simples de resolver isso é:

```java
if("quit".equals(msg)) {
```

E não haverá mais `NullPointerException`.

Ainda há o problema de um dos sockets para o cliente terminar sem nunca enviar um `quit`, e com isso ele ficaria preso no laço interno porque `br.readLine()` sempre retornaria `null`. A solução é testar o `null` no segundo `if`:

```
if(msg == null || "quit".equals(msg)) {
```

---

Há outras coisas que dá para melhorar no seu código. É possível eliminar a variáveis `condition` ao usar um `break` ou `return` ao invés de `condition = false`. O mesmo pode se aplicar ao `condition1`, em que é possível transformar o seu `while` interno em um `for`. Além disso você pode evitar ter que usar aquele `finally` horrível com *try-with-resources*. Seu código fica assim:

```java
public class Server {

    public static final int SERVERPORT = 8888;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Starting echo server...");
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);

        loop: while (true) {
            Socket s = ss.accept();

            try (InputStream is = s.getInputStream()) {
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

                for (String msg = br.readLine(); msg != null; msg = br.readLine()) {
                    System.out.println(msg);
                    if ("quit".equals(msg)) break loop;
                }
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.err.println("I/O error: " + ioe.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

E se você achar esse `for` muito complicado, pode usar um `do-while`:

```
                String msg;
                do {
                    msg = br.readLine();
                    System.out.println(msg);
                    if ("quit".equals(msg)) break loop;
                } while (msg != null);
```