# Como e quando usar "Labels" em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Em objetos/JSON usamos `:` para chaves e valores, por exemplo:

```
{x: 1}
```

Como já foi debatido em [Qual a utilização dos dois pontos em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108626/3635)

No entanto, estava trabalhando em um pequeno *script* para tentar detectar o formato JSON antes do *parse* para evitar muitos *try/catch* possíveis que eu necessitaria talvez fazer e acabei me deparando com isto:

```js
foo:console.log([1, 2, 3]);
```

Note que não é um objeto, então testei isto:

```js
foo:foo:console.log([1, 2, 3]);
```

Ele retorna o erro:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Label 'foo' has already been declared",

Creio que pela mensagem de erro isto sejam ***"Labels"***, então como e quando podemos usar Labels em JavaScript? Existe algum detalhe que diferencie o Label em JS de outras linguagens?

Comment: dica: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Answer (score 6):

Os labels servem para poder utilizar em instruções `break` e `continue`. São uma característica herdada do C, do C++ e do Java, e também existem em muitas outras linguagens tais como C#, as linguagens da família do Pascal, as linguagens da família do Visual Basic e outras. Por exemplo:

```js
a: for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    document.write("<br>");
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        if (i == 5 && j == 5) continue a;
        document.write("*");
    }
}
```

Podem ser utilizados também com `break` em blocos comuns:

```js
s: {
    document.write("antes<br>");
    break s;
    document.write("você não vai ver isto!<br>");
}
document.write("depois");
```

O uso dessa característica no JavaScript é bem raro e faz sentido apenas em situações bem específicas. Nos seus predecessores era bastante utilizado em conjunto com os `goto`s, mas como esses não foram adicionados ao JavaScript, sobrou poucas circunstâncias onde ainda seriam úteis (mas como ainda havia algumas, ele não foi eliminado da linguagem).

Já utilizei essa característica da linguagem algumas vezes em respostas aqui do SOpt. Em JavaScript, usei [**nesta resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/179050/132) e o nosso amigo Anderson Carlos Woss usou [**nesta resposta dele**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/235686/132). Em Java (que tem o mesmo funcionamento nesse caso), usei nessas daqui: [**1**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/46978/132), [**2**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/239327/132), [**3**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/242119/132), [**4**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/97011/132) e [**5**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/58681/132). Veja essas respostas para ter exemplos de uso mais reais.